# Can FHIR .NET API be used to create resources from USCORE / CARINBB profiles? if so how?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Can FHIR .NET API be used to create resources from USCORE / CARINBB profiles?
I know we cannot use partial class concept unless we fork the code and change it, So, How to create profile objects within .NET API so I can post to FHIR Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US Core and Carin BB simply constrain the allowed values for certain resources.  The resources themselves are the same.  So a US Core Lab Observation is still an Observation - and can be created using the .NET API like any other Observation.  There's no mechanism in the .NET API that exposes a US Core or Carin-BB specific API that automatically enforces those constraints.  However, you should be able to use the .NET API to validate an instance against one the profiles from those IGs so long as you load the IG package into memory.